# Effectus theory and the Giry monad

Tags: probability-theory, category-theory, monoidal-categories, monads

Is the Kleisli category of the Giry monad a monoidal effectus with copiers, in the sense of Definition 70 from [An Introduction to Effectus Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05813.pdf) ? The fact that this category is an effectus is mentioned on page 19, but I am wondering if this category is also a monoidal effectus with copiers.